# How to have nginx serve only the home page of site?

Tags: nginx, regex

I am running a server with nginx on port 80 and Apache on 8080. I want the home page of my site to be served with nginx, and every other request passed through to Apache. I found [this great article](http://kbeezie.com/apache-with-nginx/) and understand the nginx `proxy_pass` directive, but I can't figure out the right regex to tell nginx to only serve the home page of my site. Since users will come to the site by just visiting `http://mysite.com` (without `/index.htm`), I don't know what "location" value I should use.

Here's an example config file that demonstrates how to have all pages sent to Apache (like I want) except the `/css` folder, and image files. As you can see nginx uses a simple regex to specify what should be served by nginx. **What regex would I use to specify only the home page should be served by nginx? Or should I be using `try_files` somehow?**

```
server {
      root /usr/local/www/mydomain.com;
      server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

      # next line says anything that matches this regex should be sent to Apache     
      location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # Apache is listening on port 8080
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      }

      # Example 1 - Specify a folder and its contents
      # To serve everything under /css from nginx only
      location /css { }

      # Example 2 - Specify a RegEx pattern such as file extensions
      # to serve only image files directly from Nginx
      location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$
      {
            # this will match any file of the above extensions
      }
}
```

Comment: Is this a contrived example or something? It doesn't seem likely that you only want to serve the home page from nginx. The usual configuration is to serve any static files, and pass everything else upstream. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Honest, this is a real thing. The URL is going to be blasted on TV screens across America and gets a huge traffic spike, but everyone is looking for something that will be right on the home page. The rest of the site needs to be available and running, but while the TV program is on, I have a special lean home page with the thing that 99% of folks are looking for.... so they'll see what they want (on the one single nginx-served home page) and leave, and the other 1% off folks can click off from there and use the rest of the site (served by Apache through nginx reverse proxy).

Comment: Hmm, so you make the home page a static file for the duration. Takes five seconds, and doesn't require any bizarre configurations.

Comment: But the problem is a jillion people come to the site and even with the special lean (static) home page, Apache gets buried quickly. That's why I want nginx to serve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so what you really need to be doing is:

1. Serve all static files from nginx, and only pass upstream to Apache any other requests.
2. When necessary for performance reasons, make the homepage a static file such as `index.html` in the document root. Thus, nginx will serve it directly. Delete it to return to the previous behavior.

Your configuration should look something like this:

```
server {
      root /usr/local/www/mydomain.com;
      server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

      index index.html;

      location @upstream {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            # Apache is listening on port 8080
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      }

      location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @upstream;
      }
}
```

Later you should look at doing caching within your web app; if it writes generated HTML files to the disk, you could then have nginx serve those files directly out of its cache.

Comment: This seems like it should work, but my site is powered by Wordpress and it's just failing left and right-- nginx won't let me access any subdirectories, and PHP code from a WP plugin is being shown mixed in the HTML code (which obviously screws up the page). I'm guessing all this is because WP routes pages strangely, or something along those lines.

Comment: In that case, why are you using Apache at all?

Comment: Because Wordpress likes Apache and its .htaccess file... and the caching plugin I'm using does a lot to the .htaccess file as well. And I'm inheriting the whole project and not looking to rework it all :-) Good news is, I found a solution: I moved Apache up to port 8080 and kept nginx on port 80. Nginx never really serves any Apache pages; once someone clicks on the home page, I add :8080 to the URL and they're handled by Apache. Works perfectly for my needs.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Comment: Thanks for the link-- I hadn't seen that before. In browsing that page, I think it definitely shows how much Apache wants to work with .htaccess, and what a pain in the ass it is to get Wordpress (and whatever plug-ins you're using) going with nginx. That's a lot of by-hand customization. I kinda like my dual-port trick ;-) ...in all seriousness, it does the job for the two hours that the URL is broadcast on the air. The rest of the time I just run the site as a normal Apache setup since the traffic isn't spiking. Thanks for all your help and good information.

Comment: Setting it up once, means you don't have to worry about the server whenever you run a new TV campaign. It's just always ready to handle whatever you throw at it.

Comment: Agreed. For my particular case, this is the last time that it will be necessary to deal with this, as the entire site is transitioning to a new platform (which I'm not a part of) that will easily handle the traffic spikes. Thus my need to post this question and find a solution that would work without me needing to spend time rejiggering the entire server structure. Nginx fit the bill perfectly.